# Cisco Catalyst: interVLAN with shared addressing

Tags: cisco, vlan, ip

Can I make several VLANs in a typical Catalyst (for instance, Cisco C3640) that share the same addressing? For example:
vlan 1 -> address in Fa0/0.1: 3.3.3.1/29
vlan 2 -> address in Fa0/0.2: 3.3.3.2/29

Thanks

Comment: Can you explain more about what you're trying to do?  We might be able to find a way to accomplish your goal.

Comment: I know it's just for an example, but avoid using Vlan 1 on Catalysts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use same adressing that means it will be one network you can not separate it two vlan.

Comment: ok, and is it possible to have two VLANs with just one subnet, and translating the tags in the switch without using IPs in the switch interfaces?

Comment: The router is needed to the 2VLANs can communicate.  One VLAN can use one subnet. 2 VLANs can't use the same subnet at the same time.

Comment: run out of subnets? or what is your biggest problem with that network?

Comment: Other people explained that they can do this in a machine equivalent to a Catalyst, but I couldn´t find the way to do it. I´ll ask them for a detailed explanation, and I´ll post it here again :)

Comment: I learned about vlans from ccna routing and switching and i never seen same like that. Why it would be good? When you create 2 vlans, you do it because you want to separate two LANs from each other.

Comment: It can be made with private VLANs, to prevent the waste of IP addresses: http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/lan-switching/private-vlans-pvlans-promiscuous-isolated-community/40781-194.html

Answer (score 0):

You can not create saparate Vlans with same subnet , it is not feasible ..

To accomplish your requirement Configure different Vlans with different networks subnets .

And to ensure communication among this different VLANs Layer3 device is required to enable routing between different Vlans .